# html form post is not sending variable data

Tags: php, html, forms, post

After clicking "delete" (submit): I can tell that it processes the form because I get the error "You forgot to select a vendor to delete.".

The form itself is generated using PHP. When I check the HTML output, I see that the values *are* there. But when it gets to POST, nothing carries over. I'm testing and using a local host, so other than the existing action link, I'm not sure what else I can modify.

I have the exact same code in another delete form and it works fine. I literally copied the other form to create this one and just changed the SQL/Variable names.

[image: form with open drop down]
[image: form with closed drop down]

**PHP Code:**

```
#delete vendor
require('includes/mysqli_connect.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $errors = array(); //array to collect errors 

    //check to ensure fields are filled out
    if (!empty($_POST['vendor'])) {
        $vendor = trim($_POST['vendor']);
    }
    else {
        $errors[] = "<p>You forgot to select a vendor to delete</p>";
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        //insert information into appt table
        $query = "UPDATE vendors_t SET active = 0 WHERE vendorID = $vendor;";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if($result){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">';
            echo '<h2>Thank you!</h2>';
            echo '<p> Your request to delete vendorID ' . $customerID . 'has been completed </p></div>';
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($dbc);
        }
    } else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><br>';
        echo '<h2>Errors Detected</h2>';
        echo '<p>The following errors occured:<br/>';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) {
            echo "$msg<br/>\n";
        }
        echo '</p><p>Please try again. </p></div>';
    }

}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="container standout" >
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>Delete a vendor</h2>
        <p> Please select a vendor to delete.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form action="index.php?pagelet=deletevendor" method="post">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="vendor">Vendors</label>
                <select name="vendor" class="form-control">
                    <option name="vendor" selected disabled>Choose here</option>
                    <?php
                        $query = "SELECT vendorID, contactFname, contactLname, businessName FROM vendors_T WHERE active = 1;";
                        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {                   
                            echo '<option name="vendor" value="'.$row['vendorID'].'">'
                                    .$row['vendorID'].' '.$row['businessName']
                                    .' '.$row['contactFname'].' '.$row['contactLname']
                                .'</option>';
                        }?>
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" value="Delete">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see the markup for the form please, I highly suspect you have no field named "vendor" in it.

Comment: Remove **selected** from <option name="vendor" selected disabled>Choose here</option>

Comment: remove name ='vendor' from options (<option name="vendor") and add value attribute instead also remove selected.

Comment: @mayersdesign updated with form image... select drop down & label have named vendor field.

Comment: removing name="vendor" from options & removing selected both work.
After removing name="vendor" - I added selected back and it still works. 

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your option names should be the value of the vendor ID (I presume) and certainly not "vendor".

Answer (score 0):

removing name="vendor" from options & removing selected both work.

After removing name="vendor" - I added selected back and it still works.
 Thank you!!